# Get the output of a jsp file value

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to working with jsp.  However, I am working with some code that is not outputting correctly.

I am trying to get the value out of

```
 <c:if
            test="${errorCode == 'EMPPNRDP_CU' || errorCode == 'EMPPNRNOTFOUND' || errorCode == 'EMPNOUPGRADES' || errorCode == 'SEATCHANGEFAILED'|| errorCode == 'NO_RESPONSE_FIRST_ATTEMPT' || errorCode == 'NO_RESPONSE_SECOND_ATTEMPT'|| errorCode == 'UPDATEFQTVFAILED' }">
            <%  System.out.println('test') %>
            <jsp:include page="footer.jspf">
                <jsp:param name="buttons_primary" value="continue" />
                <jsp:param name="class" value="primary" />
            </jsp:include>
        </c:if>
```

I having been searching debuggin and logging methods and seem to not be doing this correct as it is throwing off my IDE.

```
<%  System.out.println('test') %>
```

This is throwing an error and not printing out test.  I am trying to find the correct format to so that I can get the  errorCode  and see why the jspf file is not showing up on the screen.

Comment: System.out.println accepts a string not a char set. It isn't html mark up or javascript its java

Comment: If it's throwing an error why don't you show us the error? Use double quotes in println.

Comment: What error is being displayed? What does the error say? Where are you attempting to get the "value"? In the logs? "anywhere"? On the page?

Comment: I was attempting to get the string initially and see if System.out works.  The errors I am getting fill the entire console in my ide.

Comment: Basically it is setting up a redirect loop in the browswer.  Not sure exactly why.